# Style changing code for website to allow users to change the size and style is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been making a website for a college assignment and a feature I wish to include is the ability to allow a user to choose a preset for the font size, font family, padding and alignment for the p and pre tags. So far I am able to create one set of preset options with a little drop down menu but I need four different selection menus to change 1/4 aspects each rather than one menu to change all 4.

The menu for the font family has been made though it does not work.

Here is the section code:

```
    <head>
    <SCRIPT src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0
    /jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

So that is in the head but the rest is here

```
<center>
<select runat="server" id="select">
<option value="1" style="background-color: white;">Standard</option>
<option value="2" style="background-color: white;">Large</option>
<option value="3" style="background-color: white;">Small</option>
</select>
</center>
<script>
$('#select').change(function(){

 if($(this).val() == '1'){

 $("p, pre").css('font-size', '18px');
  } 

 if($(this).val() == '2'){


 $("p, pre").css('font-size', '26px');
  } 

    if($(this).val() == '3'){   

 $("p, pre").css('font-size', '10px');
  }

  });
 </script>
<br/>
<center>
<select runat="server" id="select">
<option value="1" style="background-color: white;">Serif</option>
<option value="2" style="background-color: white;">Sans Serif</option>
</select>
</center>
<script>
$('#select').change(function(){

  if($(this).val() == '1'){

    $("p, pre").css('font-family', 'Georgia, serif');
  } 
  if($(this).val() == '2'){

    $("p, pre").css('font-family', 'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif');
  } 
</script>
```

So I have been playing around with it for ages but no luck. I have tried putting the two together, I've tried changing the 1, 2, 3 to different numbers but nothing..

I would rather this method improved rather than a new one though a new one will be accepted gratefully.

Comment: Please avoid using the `<center>` tag, it has been deprecated. Use CSS to center stuff instead.

Comment: The first mistake I can point out is that you have two elements with the same ID, both "select". This will cause issues.

Comment: Also, you did not close `$('#select').change(function(){`.. add `});` to close it properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

You were calling a change function to the same selector (`#select`), you should assign a unique `id` to each `select` menu and then target them in jQuery.

**Problem 2**

Syntax error: not properly closing the change function - missing `});` at the end.

**Problem 3**

Do not use `<center>` tags, they are deprecated. You can wrap your elements in a `div` and apply `text-align: center` to it with `CSS`.

---

**Correct code demo:**

```js
$('#selectSize').change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $("p, pre").css('font-size', '18px');
  }

  if ($(this).val() == '2') {
    $("p, pre").css('font-size', '26px');
  }

  if ($(this).val() == '3') {
    $("p, pre").css('font-size', '10px');
  }
});


$('#selectFont').change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == '1') {
    $("p, pre").css('font-family', 'Georgia, serif');
  }

  if ($(this).val() == '2') {
    $("p, pre").css('font-family', 'Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif');
  }
});
```

```css
.center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <select runat="server" id="selectSize">
    <option value="1" style="background-color: white;">Standard</option>
    <option value="2" style="background-color: white;">Large</option>
    <option value="3" style="background-color: white;">Small</option>
  </select>

  <select runat="server" id="selectFont">
    <option value="1" style="background-color: white;">Serif</option>
    <option value="2" style="background-color: white;">Sans Serif</option>
  </select>
</div>

<hr>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque animi soluta doloremque fuga id, porro, cupiditate ex aliquid nihil corporis consequatur libero ad repellat laboriosam voluptatum maiores accusantium nobis magni!</p>

<p>Maiores facilis ipsa consequuntur repudiandae ut esse ullam inventore nobis, cum tempora voluptatibus minus suscipit tenetur nulla dolores repellendus at molestiae, neque commodi ducimus hic? Consequuntur qui consectetur impedit fugit.</p>

<p>Sed fugiat ex omnis, consequatur accusantium, incidunt eos distinctio laborum alias quibusdam vitae labore libero nostrum est natus voluptatum harum nulla voluptatibus eveniet illum laboriosam? Distinctio sit porro harum quo.</p>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/402wemp5/1/

P.S. I recommend placing all your JavaScript code in one JS file instead of in the document. However, if you choose to keep it in the document then place them in one `<script>` tag, ideally at the bottom of `body` to ensure it can read all `DOM` elements.

Comment: It now works perfectly. It seemed that my issue was with the placement of my code. As mentioned, I did not name the select things differently though I had tried this before I submitted. I guess I just missed something obvious. Thank you for your kind and very fast assistance!

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the jquery is working by inspect elements in your browser. Next, You should set a different id for each section.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing single style rules for p & pre using $().css(), predefine the standard, small and large style using CSS elements and classes. CSS is short for "Cascading Style Sheets" which means you can define style rules in one classname and apply it to a parent element and have the rules cascade to its child elements.

For example, in your CSS file or inline `<style>` block, you can define the following rules:

```
p, pre {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
.small p, .small pre {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.large p, .large pre {
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

Then your code can do something like this:

```
<script>
$('#select').change(function(){
    var $sel = $(this),
        val = $sel.val(),
        $container = $('body');

    switch(val) {
        case '1':
           $container.removeClass('small').removeClass('large');
           break;
        case '2':
           $container.removeClass('small').addClass('large');
           break;
        case '3':
           $container.addClass('small').removeClass('large');
           break;
    }
});
</script>
```

If you want to change the style rules independently instead of grouped into 1 class, then you can define separate styles for alignment.

Comment: I will try the comment above yours first though this idea seems to work simply